# opencart editing download.php get error

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I couldn't really find a direct answer to my question and I cannot figure out why an error is getting thrown back when I am almost 99% sure I have added everything correctly. Maybe a fresh set of eyes can help.

**Question:**

I am trying to add a new column to the table that displays all the downloads that have been added, yet I get this error and cannot figure out why. I am trying to see if the download has been attached to a product yet.

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function isUsed() in /customers/b/4/a/athomestudios.net/httpd.www/admin/controller/catalog/download.php on line 178
```

**controller/catalog/download.php:**

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['downloads'][] = array(
            'download_id' => $result['download_id'],
            'name'        => $result['name'],
            'used'        => isUsed($result['download_id']),
            'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
            'edit'        => $this->url->link('catalog/download/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&download_id=' . $result['download_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
        );
    }
```

**model/catalog/download.php:**

```
public function isUsed($download_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as `total` FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_download WHERE download_id = '" . (int)$download_id . "'");

    return $query->row['total'];
}
```

**view/template/catalog/download_list.php:**

```
<?php foreach ($downloads as $download) { ?>
            <tr>
              <td class="text-center"><?php if (in_array($download['download_id'], $selected)) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $download['download_id']; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" value="<?php echo $download['download_id']; ?>" />
                <?php } ?></td>
              <td class="text-left"><?php echo $download['name']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-center">
                  <?php 
                    if ($download['used'] == 0) {
                        echo 'No';
                    }else{
                        echo 'Yes';
                    }
                  ?>
              </td>
              <td class="text-right"><?php echo $download['date_added']; ?></td>
              <td class="text-right"><a href="<?php echo $download['edit']; ?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_edit; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: could be variable scope issue. Try passing the db connection to the function.

Comment: how would I add the db connection to it?

Comment: ahhh you are correct my friend!!! i added `$this->model_catalog_download->` to the front of it and it worked.

Comment: Well seeing you're using a class here, it's unsure if a connection is being made in there. The use of `public` implies a class. You can try `public function isUsed($this->db, $download_id) {` type of thing.

Comment: ah great, glad to hear it. *Cheers!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Fred -ii- said add the db connection string.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    $data['downloads'][] = array(
        'download_id' => $result['download_id'],
        'name'        => $result['name'],
        'used'        => $this->model_catalog_download->isUsed($result['download_id']),
        'date_added'  => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
        'edit'        => $this->url->link('catalog/download/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&download_id=' . $result['download_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
    );
}
```

Comment: Always loved a happy ending ;-)